# How to catch errors and send them in an email using TALEND?

Tags: talend

I've a problem with my job. When it executes the `tLogCatcher` component, it doesn't catch errors from the error settings in `tMap`. How can I deal with this?

### This is my job's architecture

[image]

Comment: What are the settings of *tLogCatcher*?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Map Editor of the tMap component, and on the top left corner there is a button: **Setup the configurations of tMap**. It opens a **Properties Settings** window where the first checkbox is checked by default: **Die on error**. 
Uncheck it, and it generates an ErrorReject output. There are two rows what are added automatically, but it can be expanded with others.
Then you can redirect this row to **tWarn** or **tDie**, and it could be catch by **tLogCatcher**.

Comment: Also, check in *tLogCatcher* the setting *Catch tDie*.